# why we need server to run angular2 app?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have developed a front end app in angular2 using angular-cli.

then I created bundle using `ng build`

what I am really interested to know is that my app consist of only javascript & html files.

then why do I need to have a server?

My angular2 app is supposed to run directly from index.html i.e. by double clicking index.html.

isn't that right?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a server because browsers like Chrome limit how files can be accessed from the browser.

You don't need a specific server, just any HTTP server that is able to serve files so that the browser doesn't need to access them directly.